# Retrieve the position of a key from json formatted string

Tags: json, typescript

I am looking to get the position (starting offset) of a json key from a input string.

For example I want to retrieve the position of key-1 :

```
{
    "entity" : {
        "key-1" : "a",
        "key-2" : "b"
    }
}`;
```

I have try a lots of different method, but there is the closest one :

```
function getOffset(path:string)
{
    let testData = `
    { 
        "entity" : {
            "key-1" : "a",
            "key-2" : "b"
        }
    }`;

    let jsonMap = require('json-source-map');
    let stringify = jsonMap.stringify(JSON.parse((testData)));
    console.log(stringify);
    let pointer = stringify.pointers[path];
    return pointer.key;
}

export function CheckSyntax(editor:vscode.TextEditor) 
{
    let key = getOffset("/entity/key-1");
    console.log(key);
}
```

The problem is the string is transformed into an Object and loose all the references about the original string ( testData ). So I have the offset, but it's relative to a new jsonString.

Note : Using find will not doing the trick, because there will be a lots of objects with same sub-key-name.

Note bis : The final objectif is to highlight a key in error after some internal check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See examples in doc [.stringify](https://github.com/epoberezkin/json-source-map). If you remove useless stringify:

```
var jsonMap = require('json-source-map');
CheckSyntax(`{
    "entity" : {
        "key-1" : "a",
        "key-2" : "b"
    }
}`);
function getOffset(path)
{
    let testData = `
    { 
        "entity" : {
            "key-1" : "a",
            "key-2" : "b"
        }
    }`;

    let jsonMap = require('json-source-map');
    let stringify = jsonMap.parse(testData);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(stringify, null, 2));
    let pointer = stringify.pointers[path];
    return pointer.key;
}

function CheckSyntax(editor) 
{
    let key = getOffset("/entity/key-1");
    console.log(key);
}
```

And get result you wanted (key & stringify output switched):

```
null: Object {line: 3, column: 12, pos: 41}
{
  "data": {
    "entity": {
      "key-1": "a",
      "key-2": "b"
    }
  },
  "pointers": {
    "": {
      "value": {
        "line": 1,
        "column": 4,
        "pos": 5
      },
      "valueEnd": {
        "line": 6,
        "column": 5,
        "pos": 97
      }
    },
    "/entity": {
      "key": {
        "line": 2,
        "column": 8,
        "pos": 16
      },
      "keyEnd": {
        "line": 2,
        "column": 16,
        "pos": 24
      },
      "value": {
        "line": 2,
        "column": 19,
        "pos": 27
      },
      "valueEnd": {
        "line": 5,
        "column": 9,
        "pos": 91
      }
    },
    "/entity/key-1": {
      "key": {
        "line": 3,
        "column": 12,
        "pos": 41
      },
      "keyEnd": {
        "line": 3,
        "column": 19,
        "pos": 48
      },
      "value": {
        "line": 3,
        "column": 22,
        "pos": 51
      },
      "valueEnd": {
        "line": 3,
        "column": 25,
        "pos": 54
      }
    },
    "/entity/key-2": {
      "key": {
        "line": 4,
        "column": 12,
        "pos": 68
      },
      "keyEnd": {
        "line": 4,
        "column": 19,
        "pos": 75
      },
      "value": {
        "line": 4,
        "column": 22,
        "pos": 78
      },
      "valueEnd": {
        "line": 4,
        "column": 25,
        "pos": 81
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea, I have already think about that, but it's for editor plugin, so the user will format the text as he want.

Comment: No need for useless pair parse/stringify, use parse only and you are done...

Comment: Indeed, my error was to use the typescript default JSON parser instead of the one used by json-source-map. Thanks